# SQL Server- Using variables in 'IN' clause coming from a select query

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @ID SMALLINT = (SELECT ID
                        FROM ABD
                        WHERE Name IN ('myName','yourName')
                       );
SELECT * 
FROM XYZ 
WHERE ID IN (@ID)
```

Kindly suggest how to use a variable in 'IN' clause in **SQL SERVER** for the above scenario.
I know this isn't the right way. there was a similar question with a different scenario so couldn't get much help from there as well. Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you have two rows returned? Which rows value do you want? Why not just use a join instead of trying to force this by using IN?

Comment: yes it will have two rows returned. and I want both the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be to use a join instead. What you are trying to do is not going to work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM XYZ x
join ABD a on a.ID = x.ID
where a.Name in ('myName', 'yourName')
```

Comment: Your query will return data from both the `XYZ` and `ABD` tables when you just have a `SELECT *`. If you want the query to return the same data as OP, then just change the first line to `SELECT x.*` You also did not explain why OP's approach is not going to work.

Comment: @JohnOdom ROFL. It is pretty obvious the tables are just samples.

Comment: I know, just being picky on your `SELECT` :P.

Comment: I figure if they can't figure that out they should just down the computer and turn in their nerd card. :)

Answer (score 1):

A variable can only store 1 value. You can get rid of the variable and do a subquery within the IN clause like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM XYZ
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM ABD
    WHERE Name IN ('myName','yourName')
)
```

Or this subquery with the use of `EXISTS`, which is preferred over `IN` in most cases because the subquery within it will return every row for the `IN` clause while `EXISTS` will exit the subquery early when the condition has been met:

```
SELECT *
FROM XYZ x
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT a.ID
    FROM ABD a
    WHERE a.Name IN ('myName','yourName') AND a.ID = x.ID
)
```

Or you can do an `INNER JOIN` with the other table like this:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM XYZ x
    INNER JOIN ABD a ON a.ID = x.ID
WHERE a.Name IN ('myName','yourName')
```

The `x.*` will ensure that you are only returning data from the XYZ table. This is will also provide better performance than using subqueries in most cases.